# How to select multiple keyframes in Premiere?

Tags: premiere, keyframes

I had accidentally created numerous wrong keyframes, trying to tune volume. Now I would like to delete them. Unfortunately, I can't select multiple keyframes by mouse:

[image]

When I release mouse, all keyrames remain not selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in the Effects Control window:
[image]
Even if keyframes were added on the timeline, it will work.

Good luck!